# Best book for learning sensor fusion, specifically regarding IMU and GPS integration

Tags: accelerometer, physics, sensors, gyroscope, kalman-filter

I have a requirement of building an Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) from the following sensors:

- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Magnetometer

I must integrate this data to derive the attitude of the sensor platform and the external forces involved (eg. subtract tilt from linear acceleration).

I must then use this information to compliment a standard GPS unit to provide higher consistent measurements than can be provided by GPS alone.

I do understand the basic requirements of this problem:

- Integrate sensors. (To cancel noise, subtract acceleration).
- Remove noise. (Kalman filter)
- Integrate IMU measurement into GPS.

Whilst there are various libraries currently around that would do this for me (http://code.google.com/p/sf9domahrs/) I need to understand the mechanisms involved to a level where I am able to explain the techniques to other individuals after I have implemented the solution.

I have been looking at the following resources, but I am unsure which I should go for...
I need something covering Sensor Fusion, Filtering, IMU, Integration.

[Multisensor-Fusion-Integration-Intelligent-Systems](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Multisensor-Fusion-Integration-Intelligent-Systems/dp/3642100570/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1333461040&sr=8-7)

[Positioning-Systems-Inertial-Navigation-Integration](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Positioning-Systems-Inertial-Navigation-Integration/dp/0470041900/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1333461040&sr=8-4)

[Mechatronics-Intelligent-Systems-Off-road-Vehicles](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mechatronics-Intelligent-Systems-Off-road-Vehicles/dp/184996467X/ref=sr_1_11?ie=UTF8&qid=1333461040&sr=8-11)

[Autonomous-Flying-Robots-Unmanned-Vehicles](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Autonomous-Flying-Robots-Unmanned-Vehicles/dp/4431538550/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1333462213&sr=8-5)

I hope someone experienced in this area can provide any recommendations.

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe I could recommend more but I should know what you are trying to track. Pedestrians? Cars? Small airplanes? So please be more specific about your requirements and tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have implemented sensor fusion for the [Shimmer platform](http://www.shimmer-research.com/products-2/shimmer-revisions). These have been a big help:

[An introduction to inertial navigation](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk//techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-696.pdf)

[An Introduction to the Kalman Filter](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf)

[Pedestrian Localisation for Indoor Environments](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/www/files/publications/public/abr28/ojw28_thesis.pdf)